# curl http://url/script.ps1 | powershell possible?

Tags: powershell, curl, stream

I just want to replicate the same behavior that I do on Linux systems

```
c:\> \{CURL_EQUIVALENT_ON_WINDOWS} - http://url/script | powershell
```

Is that possible?

Basically I want to execute a stream I download from a server.

IE: in steps:

1) Find out how to execute streams in a powershell.
Execute a stream (that I already have on the file system)

```
c:\> type script.ps1 | powershell -command -
```

but this doesn't work.

There is an option -File to execute a "File", and basically I want to execute the stream if possible.

2) Find out how to execute a stream I download from the server and pipe it in to a powershell.

Comment: What are you expecting `| powershell` to do?

Comment: just to run the stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the command parameter of powershell with a hyphen to make it read its command from standard input. Below is an example:

```
"Write-Host This is a test" | powershell -command -
```

Example of using contents of a script file:

```
Get-Content .\test.ps1 | powershell -command -
```

From the powershell help menu:

```
powershell /?
```

> -Command
>       Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were
>       typed at the Windows PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless
>       NoExit is specified. The value of Command can be "-", a string. or a
>       script block.

```
If the value of Command is "-", the command text is read from standard
input.
```

Comment: Mmm I tried with a script: type script.ps1 | powershell -command - and it does not work :-( ther is -File option but that will be worthless, basically I want to execute the stream

Comment: I updated with an example of using the contents of script file. You need to pipe the contents of the file, not just specify the file. This will pipe the contents of the file as a string, just as downloading a file with curl would.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to dugas I learn how to execute streams with powershell, and with this link http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/11/episode-70-tangled-web.html I understand how to get content as a stream from http with powershell.

So the final curl | powershell pipe looks like this:

```
PS C:\>(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://url/script.ps1") | powershell -command -
```

Thanks a lot to everyone that contribute to this question :-)

Comment: You can also use `Invoke-Expression`: `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://url/script.ps1") | iex`. This is how [PsGet](http://psget.net/) does it.